Capturing Video and Audio from a USB device using Media Foundation on Windows
I am trying to capture video and audio from webcam using Media Foundation.
The issue is that when I enumerate video devices and then audio devices, I don't know how to match the two devices because the name is different for both... How to make sure both audio and video SYMBOLIC LINKS refer to the same webcam? Is there a way?
